# Opening a tab with canvas.toDataURL in IE11

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a canvas element that I'd like user to be able to download as an image file. The following code works in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Internet Explorer:

```
var b = document.createElement('a');

var filename = 'test.png';

b.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
b.download = filename;
b.target = '_self';
b.style.display = 'none';

// This step is needed for this to function in Firefox.
document.body.appendChild(b);
b.click();
```

I realize this exact method isn't support by IE - could I possibly just open the image data in a new tab?

Comment: can't one already right-click the canvas and save it as an image? that said, you can use my https://github.com/rndme/download lib to download in IE10+

Comment: @dandavis. While Chrome & FF support right-click saving of a canvas element, IE still does not.